# How to Subset more than Once in a Data Frame in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I have the following Data Set.

```
> eh
   PEG AEG
1    1   1
2    1   0
3    1   1
4    1   1
5    0   0
6    0   0
7    1   1
8    1   1
9    0   0
10   0   1
11   1   1
12   0   0
13   0   0
14   0   0
15   0   0
16   1   1
17   1   0
18   1   1
19   0   0
20   0   0
21   0   0
22   0   0
23   0   0
24   1   1
25   1   0
26   0   1
27   0   0
28   1   1
29   0   0
30   1   1
31   0   0
32   0   0
33   1   1
34   1   1
35   0   0
36   0   1
37   1   1
38   1   0
39   1   1
40   1   1
41   1   0
42   0   0
43   0   1
```

I am trying to find all of the columns in which both PEG and AEG equal one, and count the number of instances there are.

I understand I am close, and its probably me overlooking and not understanding the syntax since I am a beginner in R, but have tried the following code.

```
eh[which(eh$PEG == 1,) & (eh$AEG == 1,)]
```

Could anyone tell me What is wrong with the code here, and how once I do this, I could count the number of instances there?

Comment: The `PEG ==1 & AEG ==1` returns a logical vector of TRUE/FALSE i.e where both values are 1 it will be TRUE and others FALSE, `which` gives the position index of TRUE.  There are  two `,` after 1.  which is not needed.  You need `eh[eh$PEG ==1 & eh$AEG ==1,]`

Comment: Your awesome! I knew I was overlooking something simple. Is there an easy way to then count the number of instances I return to store?

Comment: Just do `with(eh, sum(PEG ==1 & AEG == 1))`

Answer (score 0):

There were some issues in the code i.e. multiple `,` in the code after the logical expression.  In `data.frame`, the indexing is documented in `?Extract`

> x[i, j, ... , drop = TRUE]

The logical expression from both cases return `TRUE/FALSE` where the column values are 1 and is joined to a single logical expression with `&` (i.e. when both cases are TRUE.  `which` returns the row position index where the value returned is `TRUE`.  Instead of this, we can directly subset using the logical index

```
eh[eh$PEG ==1 & eh$AEG ==1,]
```

---

If we want the count, it is more easier with `sum` as `TRUE` -> 1 and `FALSE` is 0, thus the `sum` of TRUE values will be the count

```
with(eh, sum(PEG ==1 & AEG == 1))
```